# Cannot Reindex Category Products and other Indexes in Magento

Tags: sql, magento, reindex

I have some of my indexes that wont run ( Product Attributes, category products) and others that seem like they are processing endlessly some do run and complete quickly however ( category flat data ). I deleted the lock files inside of Var/locks and have deleted catalog_product_flat_1, and catalog_category_product_index but the index is still not running. I recieve the following error when trying to reindex all via SSH

Product Attributes index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction' in /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:

## 0 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)

## 1 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

## 2 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)

## 3 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)

## 4 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)

## 5 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)

## 6 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Indexer/Stock/Default.php(212): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')

## 7 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Indexer/Stock/Default.php(72): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Indexer_Stock_Default->_prepareIndexTable()

## 8 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Indexer/Stock.php(248): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Indexer_Stock_Default->reindexAll()

## 9 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Indexer_Stock->reindexAll()

## 10 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()

## 11 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()

## 12 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(249): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()

## 13 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()

## 14 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()

## 15 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction' in /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:

## 0 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

## 1 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)

## 2 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)

## 3 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)

## 4 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)

## 5 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Indexer/Stock/Default.php(212): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')

## 6 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Indexer/Stock/Default.php(72): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Indexer_Stock_Default->_prepareIndexTable()

## 7 /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Indexer/Stock.php(248): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Index

Answer (score 0):

First thing i would try is to optimize / analyze / repair procedure for your Magento store tables (f.e. via phpmyadmin).

Does indexing run when flat Catalog and Product data are disabled?

How many products do you have on your store? If many products, maybe you need tune your MYSQL.